# How do I capture a sequence of what button was pressed and when?

Tags: javascript, arrays, cordova

I'm finding it really difficult to understand how javascript works, especially when writing my own code so I asked a friend to help me out and provided me with something like this.

```
var curtime = new Date();
delaytime = curtime.getTime() - previoustime.getTime();
previoustime.setTime( curtime.getTime());
temparray = new Array;
temparray.push( name );
temparray.push( delaytime );
recording.push( temparray);
```

but I can't seem to grasp the concept of how it links up to my buttons and saves them into an array. 
I would like to be able to use this recorded information to then playback exactly what the user input, but one step at a time.

If somebody could help me get to the next stage that would be greatly appreciated as I'm lost on javascript.

Comment: i dont quiet understand your question... so the first previous time is the time when the page was loaded? and the current time it will be the time when the button was pressed?

Comment: also do you have the event listener for the buttons? if so where are they? are they in vanilla javascript or using any kind of library?

Comment: I don't think when the page was loaded will be an issue.
I think the idea of it was to capture when the record button was pressed, so that will be "var curtime = new Date();" and then any buttons that I actually want recording will subtract that time to get the real time.

Comment: I'm using LowLatencyAudio plugin to preload and play the sounds.
So my HTML is "<div class="drum" id="bass" ontouchstart="play('bass');" ontouchend="touchEnd(event);">Bass</div>"

and the function it calls upon is "function play(drum) {
    document.getElementById(drum).className = 'drum touched';
    lla.play('assets/' + drum + '.mp3');
   }
   
   function touchEnd(event) {
    event.target.className = 'drum';
   }"

Answer (score 0):

Fun question. Consider the fact that each element may *fire more than one event handler for any given event*. What does that mean? You can attach both (a) a function to do 'real' work to a button as well as (b) a book-keeping function. (though, one can't guarantee the order in which they're called - they're not required to be called in the order that they were added - this may have changed, I haven't looked in around 6 months)

Also, since I've attached the event-handlers using .addEventListener, the `this` keyword refers to the html element that fired the event in the first place. - That's why I can attach a single 'generic' function to all buttons to extract any necessary information from them.

So, you just need to attach both functions to any element you'd like to log info for.
Here's a quick'n'dirty example. Hope it helps.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function onBtn1(evt)
{
    alert('you pressed button 1');
}

function onBtn2(evt)
{
    alert('btn2');
}

function onBtn3(evt)
{
    alert('pressed btn 3');
}

function onShowRecordsBtn(evt)
{
    var i, n = eventList.length;
    var tgt = byId('outputTgt');
    var msg = '';

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        // all entries except the first one must be preceded with a new-line
        if (i != 0)
            msg += "<br>";

        // show the id and time of each clicked button
        msg += "ID: " + eventList[i].elemId + " - Time: " + eventList[i].time;
    }
    tgt.innerHTML = msg;
}


// declare an empty array to hold the list of events.
var eventList = [];

function saveBtnPressInfo(evt)
{
    var curRecord = { time: new Date(), elemId: this.id};

// same as preceding line of code
//  var curRecord = { time: null, elemId: null};
//  curRecord.time = new Date();
//  curRecord.elemId = this.id;

    eventList.push(curRecord);
}

window.addEventListener('load', onPageLoaded, false);

function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function onPageLoaded(evt)
{
    // add the (unique) event handlers to the buttons
    byId('btn1').addEventListener('click', onBtn1, false);
    byId('btn2').addEventListener('click', onBtn2, false);
    byId('btn3').addEventListener('click', onBtn3, false);

    // add the event to the showEvents 'button' - I made it an inut element so that it doesn't get
    // found when we get a list of all <button> elements on the page. (I don't want to know when the user asked for button-press stats)
    byId('showRecordsBtn').addEventListener('click', onShowRecordsBtn, false);

    // add the record-keeping function to each of the buttons
    var btnList = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    var i, n = btnList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        btnList[i].addEventListener('click', saveBtnPressInfo, false);
    }
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id='btn1'>Button 1</button>
    <button id='btn2'>Button 2</button>
    <button id='btn3'>Button 3</button>
    <hr>
    <input id='showRecordsBtn' type='button' value='Show btn-click activity'/>
    <div id='outputTgt'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Here's some code that uses the (instrument)synth as found in Voxel Bukkake. In this code, I've simply played the notes in response to a click on the instrument's sample. From memory, you can use the param of .noteOn to specify the number of ms between when the call is made and when the note should be sounded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}
function toggleClass(element, newStr)
{
    index=element.className.indexOf(newStr);
    if ( index == -1)
        element.className += ' '+newStr;
    else
    {
        if (index != 0)
            newStr = ' '+newStr;
        element.className = element.className.replace(newStr, '');
    }
}
function forEachNode(nodeList, func)
{
    var i, n = nodeList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList);
    }
}


var current_time = 0;

function Instrument(attack, delay, sustain, release, sustainTime, cutoff, resonance, lfoFreq, lfoAmp, detuneSquare, detuneSaw, squareVol, sawVol, noiseVol)
{
    // volume envelope
    this.A = attack;
    this.D = delay;
    this.S = sustain;
    this.R = release;
    this.sustainTime = sustainTime;

    this.cutoff = cutoff;
    this.resonance = resonance;
    this.lfo_freq = lfoFreq;
    this.lfo_amp = lfoAmp;

    this.square_detune = detuneSquare;
    this.saw_detune = detuneSaw;

    this.square_vol = squareVol;
    this.saw_vol = sawVol;
    this.noise_vol = noiseVol;
}

function Voice(pitch, pos, ins, vol, active)
{
    this.pitch = pitch;
    this.pos = pos;     // position in samples from the beginning
    this.ins = ins;     // instrument
    this.vol = vol;
    this.xn = [0,0,0];//[1.0,1.0,1.0];
    this.yn = [0,0,0];//[1.0,1.0,1.0];
    this.active = 0;    // 0 = inactive, (not 0) = active
}

function synth(v, len, mix_buf)
{
    current_time = 100;
    var ins = v.ins;
    //var pitch_sine  = v->pitch * ins->sine_detune;
    var pitch_square = v.pitch * ins.square_detune;
    var pitch_saw    = v.pitch * ins.saw_detune;
    var vol, res, t;
    var i;
    var invSAMPLE_RATE = 1 / 44100;

    var periodo_square = 1.0/pitch_square;
    v.pos = 0;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        res=0;
        t = (v.pos+i)*invSAMPLE_RATE;
//      t >>= 0;
        // First add the oscillators

        // Sine
        //res = ins->sine_vol * msin(DOSPI*pitch_sine*t);


        // Square
        if ( (t % periodo_square) > (periodo_square/2.0))
            res += ins.square_vol;
        else
            res -= ins.square_vol;

        // Saw
        res += ins.saw_vol * ( ( (t*pitch_saw)% 2.0) - 1.0);

        // Noise
        res += ins.noise_vol * (2.0*whitenoise()-1.0) ;

        // We now apply the ADSR
        vol = getAmp(ins, t);
        res *= vol;

        // We estimate the value of applying cutoff LFO
        var cutoff, lfo_freq;
        if (ins.lfo_freq < 0)
        {
            lfo_freq = -ins.lfo_freq;
            t = current_time;
        }
        else
        {
            lfo_freq = ins.lfo_freq;
        }

        var DOSPI = 6.2831853071795862;
        cutoff= ins.cutoff + ins.lfo_amp * Math.cos(DOSPI * lfo_freq * t);

        var r = ins.resonance;
        // Calculate filter coefficients
        var c, c2,a1,a2,b1,b2;

        //We extract some calculations that are redundant in HP and LP
        var PI_samplerate = 0.000071237928652829774;
        var param_tan = PI_samplerate * cutoff;

        if (cutoff > 0.0) // Low-pass
        {
            c = 1.0 / Math.tan(param_tan);
            c2 = c*c;

            a1 = 1.0 / ( 1.0 + r * c + c2);
            a2 = 2.0 * a1;
            b1 = 2.0 * ( 1.0 - c2) * a1;
        }

        else // High-pass
        {
            c = Math.tan(-param_tan);
            c2 = c*c;

            a1 = 1.0 / ( 1.0 + r * c + c2);
            a2 = -2*a1;
            b1 = 2.0 * ( c2 - 1.0) * a1;
        }

        b2 = ( 1.0 - r * c + c2) * a1;

        v.yn[0] = (a1*res) + (a2*v.xn[1]) + (a1*v.xn[2]) - (b1*v.yn[1]) - (b2*v.yn[2]);

        v.xn[2]=v.xn[1];
        v.xn[1]=res;
        v.yn[2]=v.yn[1];
        v.yn[1]=v.yn[0];

        // From here already filtering res
        mix_buf[i] += v.yn[0] * v.vol;
    }

    v.pos+=len;

    if (vol > 0.0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

// Returns the value of time pos ADSR
// Linear interpolation
// function getAmp(instrument, pos)
function getAmp(i, pos)
{
    var A = i.A/100 + 0.00001;
    if (pos <= A)
        return (pos/A);

    pos -= A;

    var D = i.D / 100;
    var S = i.S / 100;
    if (pos <= D)
        return (1.0 - (pos * (1 - S)) / D);

    pos -= D;

    var sustain_time = i.sustainTime/100;
    if (pos <= sustain_time)
        return S;

    pos -= sustain_time;

    var R = i.R/100;
    if (pos < R)
        return S - S * (pos/R);
    else
        return 0;
}

function whitenoise()
{ 
    return Math.random();
}



////============================================================
window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);
var context;
function mInit()
{
    context = new webkitAudioContext();

    var hihat = new Instrument(  1,5,15,50,0, -12000,1.1,  1.500,8000, 1.0,0.5, 0.5,0.3,   1.2);
     var drum = new Instrument( 1,15,40,5,0,     20, 1.0, 1.0, 200, 1.5,1.0, 1.0,0.5,   2.4);

      var low = new Instrument( 1,15,40,5,0,    800,1.0, -0.500,-600, 1.0,1.0,0.4,0.7,   0.0);

    var organ = new Instrument(50,30,45,100,20,  -1150,1.0, -8.333,-950, 0.501,1.0, 0.5,0.7, 0.0);

     var lead = new Instrument( 0,10,50,40,20,    900,1.0,  1.500, 900, 0.5,1.0, 0.8,0.4,  0.0);


    var simon = new Instrument(10,10,50,75,70,    800,0.25,  1.500,700, 0.8,0.8, 0.5,0.5,  0.0);

    //function Insrument(attack, delay, sustain, release, sustainTime,   cutoff, resonance,   lfoFreq, lfoAmp, detuneSquare, detuneSaw, squareVol, sawVol, noiseVol)

    var start = new Date();

    addPlayableGraph(hihat);
//  addPlayableGraph(drum);
//  addPlayableGraph(low);
    addPlayableGraph(organ);
    addPlayableGraph(lead);
    addPlayableGraph(simon);
    var end = new Date();
    var diff = end-start;
    start = newTxt('Calculation Time: ' + diff + 'ms');
    document.body.appendChild(start);


    var coords = newEl('div');
    coords.setAttribute('id', 'coords');
    document.body.appendChild(coords);
}

function addPlayableGraph(instrument)
{
    var note = 43;
    var pitch = 440.0 * Math.pow(2.0, (note-45.0)/12.0);
    var pos = 0;
    var vol = 0.4;
    var active = 1.0;

    var voice = new Voice(pitch, pos, instrument, vol, active);
    var buffer = [];

    var i, n=4410 * (20);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        buffer[i] = 0.0;

    voice.active = synth(voice, n, buffer);

    var canvas = newEl('canvas');
    canvas.height = 96;
    canvas.width = 1024;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    drawFloatArray(buffer, canvas);

    canvas.mBuffer = buffer;
    canvas.onclick = function() { playSound(this.mBuffer, 44100, 100); };
    canvas.onmousemove = 
    function(e)
    {
        e = e || event;
        var str = 'Pos: ' + (e.clientX/canvas.width)*2000 + ',' + e.clientY;

        byId('coords').innerText = str;
    }
    return canvas;                  
}

function drawFloatArray(samples, canvas)
{
    var i, n = samples.length;
    var dur = (n / 44100 * 1000)>>0;
    canvas.title = 'Duration: ' +  dur / 1000.0 + 's';

    var width=canvas.width,height=canvas.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#303030';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
    ctx.moveTo(0,height/2);
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x = (i*width) / n;
        y = (samples[i]*height/2)+height/2;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function playSound(buffer, freq, vol)   // buffer, 44100, 0-100
{
    var mBuffer = context.createBuffer(1, buffer.length, freq);

    var dataBuffer = mBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    var soundBuffer = buffer;
    var i, n = buffer.length;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        dataBuffer[i] = soundBuffer[i];


    var node = context.createBufferSource();
    node.buffer = mBuffer;
    node.gain.value = 0.5 * vol/100.0;
    node.connect(context.destination);
    node.noteOn(0);
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly, you could look at http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/soundtoy/ for an approach that uses  a 'simple' math equation for the instrument definitions. But moe particularly - look for the code that allows a single formula (instrument) produce sounds of different pitches (if you need that)

You may simply need to use the param of .noteOn to play the mp3s you already have. Cant remember if I've played loaded sound like this, or just generated stuff.

Lots of fun, browser-generated content, that is.

Comment: this is excellent.
I think if I gave you more information I might find an answer that is more relevant.
I've made a drum machine app, so each button will play a very small mp3 clip. Play some of these buttons at the same time and you've got a drum beat!
And what I'm really looking for is a recording function which will take what the user inputs and save it. So that the user can then go back to their recording whenever they want and play it back.

Comment: You can always create the drum sounds dynamically before queuing up the notes to be played in the order and time intervals recorded. I've ported a software synth to JS (From the Voxel Bukkake 'demo'). I've also queued up a bunch of notes, such that a song can be played back, MIDI-style. I'll search for an old code-sample on my hdd.

Comment: @Joe - I've updated the answer to include some sound stuff and a link to an online 'synth'. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: The first example is great, I've changed new Date() to Date.now() to get the time in milliseconds.
Now I just need to add in a "start recording" button which will capture the time it was pressed so it can be subtracted from when bt1, bt2 or bt3 was pressed to get the difference.
And also I need a way to play back the captured information.
Is it possible to do all that?

Comment: Oh good, glad it had some utility for you. You could always forgo a 'start' button, if you were prepared for playback to start immediately and preclude any period of silence at the start of playback. Playback is easy. Just run through your array of events/notes, looking at the time after your 'start-time'. You can then use this number as the delay between calling noteOn and the time that the sound starts. I've implemented a basic tracker that does exactly this. The whole song is cued-up before a single note is played. At the risk of bloat, I'll post it as an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Two basic approaches to playback can be taken. You can either work out the delay between each note, then play each note one-by-one, waiting for the period between each note before playing the next one with noteOn(0). This would consume the least memory but would preclude more than one note being started simultaneously.

The other approach would be to determine the time from playback start to each individual note and then cue them all up before sound output starts. You need more memory, but I find it a more intuitive approach. You can also fire a bunch of notes off at the same time - like you need to for a chord, for example.

I've adopted the second approach with this code. You'll need to supply your own sound samples (6 of) and have to run it via localhost, rather than just double-clicking it from the folder. I think it's because I used AJAX to load the samples.

The samples came from "chiptune.xm", as found in the code here: https://forum.tuts4you.com/files/file/184-snd-keygen-template-code-walker/ (registration required)
You can extract the samples with any one of a bunch of (amiga) 'mod players' - The song is about 2m18s long and is only 25kb on disk, since it uses 8bit mono samples at about 8khz or 11khz - haven't managed to define something sound close enough to them algorithmically yet though, so I just use the WAVs I extracted from it.

The functionality which has the most relevance to this question should be found in playSong2(). That gets the current note for each of the instruments at each 0.12sec step of the song. It resamples the note to be longer or shorter so as to get the different pitches required, before sending off the data to be queued up for playing with a call to noteOn.
Anyhow, I'm rather busy at the moment and hope that the little I've been able to do helps you. :)

Have fun!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}
function toggleClass(element, newStr)
{
    index=element.className.indexOf(newStr);
    if ( index == -1)
        element.className += ' '+newStr;
    else
    {
        if (index != 0)
            newStr = ' '+newStr;
        element.className = element.className.replace(newStr, '');
    }
}
function forEachNode(nodeList, func)
{
    var i, n = nodeList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);
var guitar1, tmpContext;
var instruments = [];
function mInit()
{
    instruments.push(new sampledSound('audio/st88gbass.wav'));
    instruments.push(new sampledSound('audio/st03church.wav'));
    instruments.push(new sampledSound('audio/st88snare13.wav'));
    instruments.push(new sampledSound('audio/st03bastrumma.wav'));
    instruments.push(new sampledSound('audio/st03bassdrum6.wav'));
    instruments.push(new sampledSound('audio/st03guitar7.wav'));


//  instruments.forEach( function(elem){elem.canvas.addEventListener('click', mClick2, false);} );

/*  
    var rawSnd = new rawSound('audio/salida.raw.bin');
*/
    tmpContext = new webkitAudioContext();
}

function getFreq(noteNum)
{
    var pitch = 440.0 * Math.pow(2.0, (noteNum-45.0)/12.0);
    return pitch;
}

function mClick2()
{
//  function playSamples(floatArray, startTime)
//  function reSample(srcArray, origNote, newNote)

    var origNote = 36, newNote = 35;
    var newSamples;
//var samples = this.mBuffer.getChannelData(0); 
    var curTime = tmpContext.currentTime;

    newSamples = reSample(this.sampledSound.mBuffer.getChannelData(0), origNote, newNote);
    playSamples(newSamples, curTime + 0.3);

}


function mClick()
{
    var origNote = 36;
    var newNote = 37;

    var k = getFreq(origNote) / getFreq(newNote); //c4Hz / a3Hz;

    var srcBuffer = this.sampledSound.mBuffer;
    var srcSamples = srcBuffer.getChannelData(0);

//  alert('continue to play note D4 - ' + k + ' * the # of samples');
    var srcX, srcY, srcWidth, dstX, dstWidth, dstY;
    var srcX, srcDx;
    var dstSamples = new Float32Array();

    dstWidth = (srcSamples.length * k) >> 0;
    srcWidth = srcSamples.length;

    for (dstX=0; dstX<dstWidth; dstX++)
    {
        srcX = ((dstX / dstWidth) * srcWidth) >> 0;
        srcY = srcSamples[srcX];

        dstSamples[dstX] = srcY;
    }

//  alert("Source samples (" + c4Hz + 'hz): ' + srcSamples.length + '\n'
//       +"Dest samples (" + d4Hz + 'hz): ' + dstSamples.length);


    tmpBuffer = tmpContext.createBuffer(1, dstWidth, 44100);
    var datBuf = tmpBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    var inBuf = dstSamples;
    var i, n = dstWidth;
//  datBuf = inBuf;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        datBuf[i] = inBuf[i];

    var node = tmpContext.createBufferSource();
    node.buffer = tmpBuffer;
    var volume = 100;
    node.gain.value = 0.5 * volume/100.0;
    node.connect(tmpContext.destination);
    var startTime=tmpContext.currentTime;//+0.100;
    node.noteOn(startTime + 0.30);
}


var patterns =
        // all patterns use the organ track
        [
            //      0,          0,      5,      6,      6,          2,          2,          1,          1,          6,      6,          2,          2,          1,      1
            [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,6], [1,2,3,6], [1,2,3,7], [1,2,3,7],  [1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,6], [1,2,3,6], [1,2,3,7], [1,2,3,7],

            //      6
            [1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,4]
        ]

    // 0,0,5,6,6,2,2,1,1,6,6,2,2,1,1,6,5,3,

var tracks = 
        [
                // 1 - organ track
                [ 
                    [31,0x82],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],
                    [ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[31,0x82],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],
                    [ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],
                    [31,0x82],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],
                    [29,0x82],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],
                    [ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[29,0x82],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],
                    [ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],
                    [29,0x82],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00],[ 0,0x00]
                ],


                // 2 - bass drum
                [ 
                    [38,1],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[36,1],[0,0],[38,1],[0,0],
                    [0,0],[0,0],[36,1],[0,0],[38,1],[0,0],[41,1],[0,0],
                    [0,0],[0,0],[41,1],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[41,1],[0,0],
                    [40,1],[0,0],[38,1],[0,0],[36,1],[0,0],[38,1],[0,0],
                    [38,1],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[36,1],[0,0],[38,1],[0,0],
                    [0,0],[0,0],[36,1],[0,0],[38,1],[0,0],[41,1],[0,0],
                    [0,0],[0,0],[41,1],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[41,1],[0,0],
                    [40,1],[0,0],[38,1],[0,0],[36,1],[0,0],[38,1],[0,0]
                ],

                // 3 - bastruma and basdrumb 
                [ 
                    [43,4],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],[41,3],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],
                    [43,4],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],[41,3],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],
                    [43,4],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],[41,3],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],
                    [43,4],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],[41,3],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],
                    [43,4],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],[41,3],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],
                    [43,4],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],[41,3],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],
                    [43,4],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],[41,3],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],
                    [43,4],[0,0],[47,5],[0,0],[41,3],[41,3],[41,3],[41,3]
                ],

                // 4 - guitar7
                [ 
                    [43,0x06],[0,0],[38,0x86],[0,0],[41,0x86],[0,0],[47,0x46],[0,0],
                    [43,0x46],[0,0],[38,0x46],[0,0],[41,0x46],[0,0],[47,0x46],[0,0],

                    [43,0x46],[0,0],[47,0x46],[0,0],[41,0x46],[0,0],[47,0x46],[0,0],
                    [41,0x06],[0,0],[41,0x46],[0,0],[40,0x46],[0,0],[40,0x46],[0,0],

                    [38,0x06],[0,0],[33,0x86],[0,0],[38,0x46],[0,0],[33,0x46],[0,0],
                    [38,0x46],[0,0],[33,0x46],[0,0],[38,0x46],[0,0],[33,0x46],[0,0],

                    [38,0x46],[0,0],[33,0x46],[0,0],[38,0x46],[0,0],[33,0x46],[0,0],
                    [38,0x26],[0,0],[33,0x26],[0,0],[38,0x26],[0,0],[33,0x26],[0,0]
                ],

                // 5 - guitar7
                [ 
                    [43,0x06],[0,0],[38,0x86],[0,0],[43,0x46],[0,0],[38,0x46],[0,0],
                    [43,0x46],[0,0],[38,0x46],[0,0],[43,0x46],[0,0],[38,0x46],[0,0],

                    [43,0x06],[0,0],[38,0x86],[0,0],[43,0x46],[0,0],[38,0x46],[0,0],
                    [41,0x06],[0,0],[41,0x86],[0,0],[41,0x46],[0,0],[41,0x46],[0,0],

                    [41,0x06],[0,0],[45,0x86],[0,0],[41,0x46],[0,0],[45,0x46],[0,0],
                    [41,0x46],[0,0],[45,0x46],[0,0],[41,0x46],[0,0],[45,0x46],[0,0],

                    [38,0x06],[0,0],[33,0x86],[0,0],[38,0x06],[0,0],[45,0x86],[0,0],
                    [38,0x46],[0,0],[45,0x46],[0,0],[38,0x06],[0,0],[45,0x46],[0,0]
                ],
                //
                // 6 - guitar7
                [ 
                    [38,0x06],[0,0],[33,0x86],[0,0],[36,0x06],[0,0],[38,0x06],[0,0],
                    [33,0x86],[0,0],[36,0x06],[0,0],[38,0x06],[0,0],[41,0x06],[0,0],

                    [36,0x86],[0,0],[41,0x06],[0,0],[36,0x86],[0,0],[41,0x06],[0,0],
                    [40,0x06],[0,0],[38,0x06],[0,0],[36,0x06],[0,0],[38,0x06],[0,0],

                    [38,0x06],[0,0],[33,0x86],[0,0],[36,0x06],[0,0],[38,0x06],[0,0],
                    [33,0x86],[0,0],[36,0x06],[0,0],[38,0x06],[0,0],[41,0x06],[0,0],

                    [36,0x86],[0,0],[41,0x06],[0,0],[36,0x86],[0,0],[41,0x06],[0,0],
                    [40,0x06],[0,0],[38,0x06],[0,0],[36,0x06],[0,0],[38,0x06],[0,0]
                ],
                //
                // 6 - guitar7
                [ 
                    [43,0x06],[0,0],[43,0x86],[0,0],[38,0x46],[0,0],[43,0x46],[0,0],
                    [43,0x06],[0,0],[43,0x86],[0,0],[43,0x06],[0,0],[38,0x06],[0,0],

                    [43,0x86],[0,0],[38,0x46],[0,0],[43,0x46],[0,0],[38,0x06],[0,0],
                    [41,0x06],[0,0],[43,0x06],[0,0],[43,0x86],[0,0],[41,0x06],[0,0],

                    [41,0x86],[0,0],[45,0x46],[0,0],[41,0x46],[0,0],[41,0x06],[0,0],
                    [40,0x06],[0,0],[38,0x06],[0,0],[43,0x46],[0,0],[41,0x06],[0,0],

                    [41,0x86],[0,0],[45,0x46],[0,0],[41,0x46],[0,0],[45,0x46],[0,0],
                    [41,0x46],[0,0],[45,0x26],[0,0],[41,0x26],[0,0],[45,0x26],[0,0]
                ]
                //
        ];

var rowTime = 0.12;



function playSong()
{
    var numTracks = tracks.length;
    var numRows = tracks[0].length;

    var curRow, curTrack, curNote;
    var startTime = tmpContext.currentTime + 1.0;
    var newSamples;

    for (curTrack=0; curTrack<numTracks; curTrack++)
    {
        for (curRow=0; curRow<numRows; curRow++)
        {
            curNote = tracks[curTrack][curRow];
            if (curNote[0] != 0)
            {
                newSamples = new Float32Array();
                newSamples = reSample( instruments[curNote[1]-1].mBuffer.getChannelData(0), 36, curNote[0]);
                playSamples(newSamples, curRow * rowTime + startTime);
            }
        }
    }
    alert('numTracks: ' + numTracks + ' - numRows: ' + numRows);
}


//patterns
function playSong2()
{
    var nPatterns = patterns.length;
    var curPattern, patternIndex, nTracks, nRows, songRow, startTime, newSamples;
    var rowTime = 0.12;
    var startTime = tmpContext.currentTime + 1.0;
    var curVol, curInstr;

    for (patternIndex=0; patternIndex<nPatterns; patternIndex++)
    {
        curPattern = patterns[patternIndex];
        nTracks = curPattern.length;
        songRow = patternIndex * 64;
        console.log(curPattern);

        for (trackIndex=0; trackIndex<nTracks; trackIndex++)
        {
            if (curPattern[trackIndex] != 0)
            {
                curTrack = tracks[ curPattern[trackIndex] - 1 ];
                nRows = curTrack.length;

                for (rowIndex=0; rowIndex<nRows; rowIndex++)
                {
                    curNote = curTrack[rowIndex];
                    if (curNote[0] != 0)
                    {
    //                  var nt = newTxt('play note');
    //                  document.body.appendChild(nt);
                        curVol = curNote[1] >> 4;
                        curInstr = (curNote[1] & 0xF) - 1;
                        newSamples = new Float32Array();
                        newSamples = reSample( instruments[curInstr].mBuffer.getChannelData(0), 36, curNote[0]);

                        if (curVol == 0)
                            playSamples(newSamples, ((songRow+rowIndex) * rowTime) + startTime);
                        else
                            playSamples(newSamples, ((songRow+rowIndex) * rowTime) + startTime, (curVol * 100) / 0x0f );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

// volume is optional, range is 0..100. If not specified, 100 is used;
function playSamples(floatArray, startTime, volume)
{
    var tmpBuffer = tmpContext.createBuffer(1, floatArray.length, 44100);
    var datBuf = tmpBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    var inBuf = floatArray;
    var i, n = inBuf.length;
//  datBuf = inBuf;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        datBuf[i] = inBuf[i];

    var node = tmpContext.createBufferSource();
    node.buffer = tmpBuffer;
    if (volume === undefined)
        var volume = 100;
    node.gain.value = 0.5 * volume/100.0;
    node.connect(tmpContext.destination);
//  var startTime=tmpContext.currentTime;//+0.100;
    node.noteOn(startTime);
}

function reSample(srcArray, origNote, newNote)
{
    var k = getFreq(origNote) / getFreq(newNote);
    var srcWidth = srcArray.length;
    var dstWidth = (srcWidth * k) >> 0;

    var newSamples = new Float32Array(dstWidth);
    var dstX, srcX, srcY;

    for (dstX=0; dstX<dstWidth; dstX++)
    {
        srcX = ((dstX / dstWidth) * srcWidth) >> 0;
        srcY = srcArray[srcX];

        newSamples[dstX] = srcY;
    }
    return newSamples;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function rawSound(sndSampleUrl, canvas)
{
    this.mContext = new webkitAudioContext();

    this.request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.request.open('GET', sndSampleUrl, true);
    this.request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    this.mBuffer = [];

    var canvas = newEl('canvas'); //byId('output');
    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 100;
    canvas.sampledSound = this;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    canvas.onclick = function(){ this.sampledSound.play(); };

    // Decode asynchronously
    var me = this;
    this.request.onload = 
    function(e)
    {
        me.mBuffer = new Int16Array(this.response);
        tmpBuffer = new Int16Array(this.response);

        me.convertedBuffer = [];

        var i, n = tmpBuffer.length;
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            me.convertedBuffer[i] = tmpBuffer[i] / 32768;
        }
        me.mBuffer = me.mContext.createBuffer(1, n, 44100);

    //  var msg = newTxt('Retrieved ' + sndSampleUrl + '(' + me.request.response.byteLength + ' bytes)');
    //  document.body.appendChild(msg);
    //  document.body.appendChild(newEl('br'));

    //  var msg = newTxt('Samples: ' + tmpBuffer.length + ', Secs: ' + ( (((tmpBuffer.length/44100)*1000)>>0)/1000));
    //  document.body.appendChild(msg);
        drawFloatArray(me.convertedBuffer, canvas);
        //me.mContext.decodeAudioData(me.request.response, function(buffer) {me.mBuffer = buffer;me.drawSound(canvas);}, onErrorFn);
//      alert('Retrieved ' + sndSampleUrl + '(' + me.request.response.byteLength + ' bytes)' );
    }
    this.request.send();
}

rawSound.prototype.play = function()
{
    var dataBuffer = this.mBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    var soundBuffer = this.convertedBuffer;
    var i, n = soundBuffer.length;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        dataBuffer[i] = soundBuffer[i];

    var node = this.mContext.createBufferSource();
    node.buffer = this.mBuffer;
    node.gain.value = 0.5 * this.mVolume/100.0;
    node.connect(this.mContext.destination);
    node.noteOn(0);
}


function drawFloatArray(samples, canvas)
{
    var i, n = samples.length;
    var dur = (n / 44100 * 1000)>>0;
    canvas.title = 'Duration: ' +  dur / 1000.0 + 's';

    var width=canvas.width,height=canvas.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#303030';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
    ctx.moveTo(0,height/2);
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x = (i*width) / n;
        y = (samples[i]*height/2)+height/2;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function sampledSound(sndSampleUrl, canvas)
{
  this.request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  this.request.open('GET', sndSampleUrl, true);
  this.request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  this.mBuffer = [];
  this.mContext = new webkitAudioContext();
  this.loaded = false;
  var canvas = newEl('canvas'); //byId('output');
  canvas.width = 500;
  canvas.height = 100;
  canvas.sampledSound = this;
  this.canvas = canvas;
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  canvas.onclick = function(){ this.sampledSound.play(); };
  // Decode asynchronously
  var me = this;
  this.request.onload = function(){me.mContext.decodeAudioData(me.request.response, function(buffer) {me.mBuffer = buffer;me.drawSound(canvas);me.loaded=true;}, onErrorFn);}
  this.request.send();
}

sampledSound.prototype.play = function()
{
    var source = this.mContext.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = this.mBuffer; //bufferList[soundIndex];
    source.connect(this.mContext.destination);
    source.noteOn(0);
}

sampledSound.prototype.drawSound = function(canvas)
{
//  var msg = 'Canvas size: ' + canvas.width + 'x' + canvas.height + 'px';
//  msg += "\n - " + this.mBuffer.duration + ' seconds';
//  alert(msg);
    var dur = (this.mBuffer.duration * 1000)>>0;
    canvas.title = 'Duration: ' +  dur / 1000.0 + 's';

    canvas.width = (dur/1000 * 512)>>0;
    canvas.style.width = (dur/1000 * 512)>>0 + 'px';


    var width=canvas.width, height=canvas.height;
    var x,y, i, n = this.mBuffer.length;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var samples = this.mBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#303030';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
    ctx.moveTo(0,height/2);
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x = (i*width)/n;
        y = (samples[i]*height/2)+height/2;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
function onErrorFn()
{
    alert('f#@ker');
}

</script>
<style>
    canvas
    {
/*      width: 250px; */
        height: 100px;
        padding: 4px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick='playSong2();'>playSong</button>
</body>
</html>
```